# More space-efficient way to retrieve counts from an enormous table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, performance

I am working with an enormous customer record table, (roughly 62 million customers,) and I need to retrieve counts for each customer. Presently, there is an Order table and a Unique Customers table. I perform a simple Inner Join to retrieve the records.

However, due to the size of the Orders table, the temporary file exceeds 15 GB. This is problematic, as the client has limited space available. Is there there a more space-efficient way to retrieve the counts than my current query?

```
SELECT A.CustomerID
  ,B.OrderID
  ,count(distinct B.OrderID) as Num_Orders
FROM UniqueCustomers as A
INNER JOIN Orders as B on A.CustomerID = B.CustomerID
GROUP BY A.CustomerID, B.OrderID
```

Thanks for your insight!

Comment: With such a big amount of data I doubt you will be using all the extracted records anyway. Are you showing the results in a grid? Are you exporting them to flat file? I think you should be able to segment or paginate the results, and thus reducing the temp file.

Comment: Why do you need to involve the customer table at all? All you're getting there is the customerID, which also exists in the orders table. Also, why do you need to apply distinct to OrderID? Does your Orders table really allow duplicate values for OrderID?

Comment: Why do you need to join to UniqueCustomers at all?

Comment: I do end up using all the records. Essentially, I compile a series of characteristics for each customer and these are then exported in a flat file to be used in a regression model. A crucial metric is the number of orders and types of orders placed by each customer.

Comment: Also what is the point of including OrderID in the SELECT? Do you want a count or a list? You need to pick one.

Comment: To answer your question Aaron, the Unique customers are specifically selected. So while there may be 62 million orders for say, 3 million customers I may ultimately be interested in only a subset of the 3 million. Oh the joys of inheriting projects...

Comment: Don't you have table with OrderID as primary key? It seems that your database is not normalized then.

Comment: That is a very good point about the OrderID. I had inherited most of this code from someone else and it never occurred to me that there is a dichotomy between the counts and list. Thanks a ton!

Comment: You should give the table `UniqueCustomers` a more meaningful name. If it is a subset of customers selected for some specific reason, name it as such. `UniqueCustomers` doesn't imply that at all - it just sounds like all of the customers there are unique - which is different from the base customers table how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No idea why you included `OrderID` in the output list - you are trying to get counts, right, not a list of 62 million `OrderID`s? Additionally I am not sure why you need to apply `DISTINCT` to `OrderID` - your `Orders` table should not allow for duplicate values here; if it does, your schema is messed up.

Also it can be more efficient to use an `EXISTS` clause instead of a `JOIN` - however that can flip if you are using `SELECT INTO`.

```
SELECT CustomerID, Num_Orders = COUNT(OrderID)
  FROM dbo.Orders AS o
  WHERE EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.UniqueCustomers WHERE CustomerID = o.CustomerID
  )
  GROUP BY CustomerID;
```

Comment: @Gordon check the comments - I updated it because the OP wants a subset, as defined by `UniqueCustomers`, as opposed to all customers, as defined by `Customers`. Terrible name for a table that represents a subset of the customers, but hey, not my schema. :-)

Comment: Don't get me started on this database. Horrible name conventions and many tables did not even have primary key constraints. It's nightmarish but I need to work with it. Thanks a ton for your answer!